# How to use v-bind properly (vue.js)

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a `Vue.component` which creates a row in a table:

```
 Vue.component('comment-row', {
                props: ['comment'],
                template: '<tr>' +
                    '<th>{{comment.authorName}}</th>' +   // works fine
                    '<th>{{comment.value}}</th>' +  // also works fine
                    '<th><form action="/remove_comment/{{comment.id}}">' +  // problem here
                    '<button type="submit">X</button></form></th>' +
                    '</tr>'
            });
```

The row looks like:

Author | Some message | Button 'X' to delete this row with unique action

And there is a problem here:
[Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJF69.jpg)

Ok, we do what we are asked:

```
<form v-bind:action="/remove_comment/comment.id">
```

But here another problem arises:
[Invalid regular expression flags in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRMIx.jpg)

Instead of a number I get string `comment.id`

The question is how to use `['comment']` prop correctly in a html tag `action = ""` in Vue.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use v-bind like this:

```
<form v-bind:action="'/remove_comment/' + comment.id"></form>
```

Or use a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) for cleaner code
`v-bind:action="mycomputedProperty"`

Answer (score 1):

Shorthand Version of Iwan's Answer.

Reference from vue.js [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand)

```
<form :action="'/remove_comment/' + comment.id"></form>
```